# Translate first order logic formula to English mathematical statement

Tags: first-order-logic, logic-translation

Here are the questions
[image]

My solution:

(a) Any integer has an inverse

(b) Any nature number is either even or odd

(c) There exists an identity nature number. (I don't know what it calls, 1 time any number is the number itself.)

(d) Don't know

(e) Don't know

(f) There exists a quadratic function in R (I think I should use $0$ somewhere)

Can anyone help me with (d), (e) and check the others?

Comment: For f I think it is that any 2nd degree function has a root

Comment: @RSerrao Noooo, remember that if $b^2-4ac<0$, the quadratic has no real root.

Comment: i didn't say it was true. It is just what is written there. I know it is not true

Comment: @RSerrao But the structure restrict in R

Answer (score 0):

a)  Right idea, but you need to say here that the 'inverse' is relative to addition. That is, for every integer x there is an integer '-x' (where x + (-x) = 0)

b) Good!

c) Again, you need to be a bit more specific: this time, the 'identity' element is relative to multiplication.  (Also, technically, it only says that there is a 'right-identity' element z, that is: $x*z=x$, and it does not say it is a 'left-identity' element: $z*x=x$.  Typically, for something to be an identity element it needs to be a right and left identity element.)

d) This one is like a), but for multiplication: it says that every non-zero natural number has an inverse relative to multiplication, i.e. for any x there is a y such that $x*y = 1$ (which is of course not true, but that is what the statement says)

e) This one is a little weird, and I have a hard time putting it into a fluent English sentence, but basically it says that multiplication (for integers) has a left-identity element (the y), and that two times that identity element is a perfect square (which again is not true, since y would have to be 1, and 2 is not a perfect square)

f) As pointed out, this is saying that every quadratic function has a root (which is again not true, but that is what it says)